# Was ist der Unterschied grammatisch zwischen diesen zwei Sätzen? Und sind beide korrekt?

Tags: grammaticality, grammar-identification

Was ist der Unterschied grammatisch zwischen diesen zwei Sätzen? Und sind beide korrekt?

1. **Das** Bild des Anderen in der Reiseliteratur.
2. Bild des Anderen in der Reiseliteratur.

Comment: Beides sind nur Satzfragmente, denn es fehlt das Prädikat, und beim zweiten Beispiel fehlt zusätzlich ein zu _Bild_ gehörender Artikel.

Comment: Are these fragments intended as headlines? What is referenced to by *"das Andere"*?

Comment: @Takkat Yes, it's intended as a headline or a title.The orginal text is  "The image of the Other in the travel litterature"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beide Beispielsätze sind keine vollständigen Sätze im grammatischen Sinn, da ihnen das Prädikat fehlt (also: ein Verb, eventuell plus ergänzendem Krimskrams). Alles deutet darauf hin, dass es sich um Überschriften wie etwa Buchtitel handelt.

> Das Bild des Anderen in der Reiseliteratur

wäre ein typischer Buchtitel

> Bild des Anderen in der Reiseliteratur

wäre als Buchtitel untypisch; eher kann man sich dies als eine von mehreren Überschriften im Rahmen einer wissenschaftlichen Arbiet vorstellen. Der Drang zur Kürze mag hier zum Weglassen des "das" führen. Allerdings fühlt sich die Überschrift damit immer noch wie eine leicht verstümmelte Kurzform an. Eleganter wäre die Kapitelüberschrift, wenn das "das" noch dabei wäre.

Comment: Ich kann mir keinen noch so grossen Drang zur Kürze vorstellen, der das Weglassen eines Artikels in diesem Beispiel rechtfertigte. Stünde "Bild" im Plural, wärs anders.

Comment: Das Vorkommen ohne das vorangestellte "Das" dürfte hauptsächlich bei Über- oder Unterschriften von Abbildungen innerhalb eines Textes vorkommen: "Bild der Kathedrale von Norden aus". Allerdings passt der konkrete Beispielsatz aus der Fragestellung nicht wirklich zu einer Abbildungs-Beschriftung.